# Como conseguir enviar o content_type original de um arquivo para o S3 (min.io)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-aws

Estou tendo um problema muito grande em relação aos uploads feitos para o S3 (Na verdade eu estou utilizando o [Minio](https://min.io/) que é um  sistema compatível com o S3).

Para isso utilizo a gem `aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1.96'`

Esse é o método que estou utilizando para enviar esse arquivo para o Minio.

```
  def upload_file(file)
    object_key = "#{Time.now.to_i}-#{file.original_filename}"
    object = @s3_bucket.object(object_key)
    object.upload_file(Pathname.new(file.path))
    
    object
  end
```

Eu recebo `file` via `request` e está tudo ok com ele, principalmente a parte que está me dando dor de cabeça... o `Content Type`.

```
# file
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f47918ef708
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers=
  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"image_test.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @original_filename="image_test.jpg",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20220120-9-gc3x7n.jpg>>
```

O problema é que quando eu faço esse upload dessa forma ele é fica no (Minio)[1](https://min.io/) com o Content Type como `"binary/octet-stream"` e não como `image/jpeg` como o arquivo original.

[image: Imagens no Minio como arquivo binário]

No final, eu preciso coletar a URL desse arquivo para enviar para outro sistema, esse sistema verifica esse `Content Type`, mas como está sempre indo como binário, sempre vai gerar erro.

Existe alguma forma de ou enviar esse arquivo com o `content type`  ou gerar essa URL final fornecendo o `Content Type` correto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta é bem mais simples do que encontrá-la, podemos usar o método [put_objec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#put_object-instance_method)t que possui, como parâmetro, a opção de informar o content-type:

```rb
  def upload_file(file)
    object_key = "#{Time.now.to_i}-#{file.original_filename}"
    object = @s3_bucket.object(object_key)

    @s3_bucket.put_object(
      body: file.read, 
      key: object_key, 
      content_type: file.content_type
    )
    
    object
  end
```